# How to include chart js annotations in ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, chart.js

I am trying to include this annotation in my project in ember, this is th link to the plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-plugin-annotation.
I tried

```
npm i chartjs-plugin-annotation
```

but still no luck, 
i tried this also

```
npm i chartjs-plugin-annotation --save
```

Is there another way to incude this plugin in ember?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include it as `bower` dependency with `bower install` command.

After including it to the project,In `ember-cli-build.js` file, use `app.import` to add it to build as following (please check the path):

```
app.import('bower_components\chartjs-plugin-annotation\chartjs-plugin-annotation.min.js');
```

If you don't want to use `bower` and if you prefer `npm`, then have a look at broccoli family. It is a bit long way.

Comment: @kumkanillam Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

add npm [package](https://github.com/ef4/ember-auto-import)

`ember install ember-auto-import`

ember-cli-build.js

```
/* eslint-env node */
'use strict';

const EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');

module.exports = function (defaults) {
  let app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
    autoImport: {
      alias: {
        'chartjs-plugin-datalabels': 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels/dist/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.js',
      },
    }
  });
  return app.toTree();
};
```

import in component-name.js

```
import 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels'
```